Visual Studio .sln changes when adding existing project that do not relate to added project
When i add an existing project to my solution, visual studio makes changes to lines concerning other projects in the sln file.
For example i added the MyProjectE to my solution which already existed before.
Before:
...
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.408219.2
Project("{FE45H815-301F-11D3-BF4B-01JG812DI512}") = "MyProjectA", "MyProjectA\MyProjectA.csproj", "{5E1498BF-4BFA-65DB-B7B8-884JK349JK21}"
EndProject
Project("{FE45H815-301F-11D3-BF4B-01JG812DI512}") = "MyProjectB", "MyProjectB\MyProjectB.csproj", "{E1D124F0-AB44-4145-8997-24F2B7C249B8}"
EndProject
Project("{FE45H815-301F-11D3-BF4B-01JG812DI512}") = "MyProjectC", "MyProjectC\MyProjectC.csproj", "{420DJKLA-7D92-4ED2-B18A-7F92123SR920}"
EndProject
Project("{FE45H815-301F-11D3-BF4B-01JG812DI512}") = "MyProjectD", "MyProjectD\MyProjectD.csproj", "{E1D124F0-295C-44BE-8A56-C3050AB49E4E}"
EndProject
Global
...

After:
...
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.408219.2
Project("{89F231D1-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "MyProjectA", "MyProjectA\MyProjectA.csproj", "{5E1498BF-4BFA-65DB-B7B8-884JK349JK21}"
EndProject
Project("{89F231D1-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "MyProjectB", "MyProjectB\MyProjectB.csproj", "{E1D124F0-AB44-4145-8997-24F2B7C249B8}"
EndProject
Project("{FE45H815-301F-11D3-BF4B-01JG812DI512}") = "MyProjectC", "MyProjectC\MyProjectC.csproj", "{420DJKLA-7D92-4ED2-B18A-7F92123SR920}"
EndProject
Project("{FE45H815-301F-11D3-BF4B-01JG812DI512}") = "MyProjectD", "MyProjectD\MyProjectD.csproj", "{E1D124F0-295C-44BE-8A56-C3050AB49E4E}"
EndProject
Project("{89F231D1-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "MyProjectE", "MyProjectE\MyProjectE.csproj", "{28BEA2B4-42DC-4F84-843B-5070AD9AE335}"
EndProject
Global
...

What happens is, that the reference of the new project is added at the bottom which is completely fine. However, as you can see in the first two lines, the first "ID's" of MyProjectA and MyProjectB changed from:
Project("{FE45H815-301F-11D3-BF4B-01JG812DI512}") = "MyProjectA" ...
to:
Project("{89F231D1-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "MyProjectA" ...
The official documentation calls two ID's in each line

the unique project GUID and the project type GUID.

However i am not sure, if the GUID that changes in my problem is the project GUID or the project type GUID because of this stack overflow answer.
So my question is, what exactly is the value that changes, what could be the reason, why the value changes and if i need to take any action because i am not sure, if i have to add these changes in my commits.
Thanks in advance :)

The value that changes in the project file is the Project Type GUID.
The GUID enclosed in braces {} immediately after Project is the Project Type GUID.
Visual Studio may have detected a different project type or template for the newly added project (MyProjectE), resulting in a different Project Type GUID being assigned.
Changes in the project structure, configuration, or settings may have triggered a re-assignment of the Project Type GUID.
Updates or modifications made to Visual Studio or its project management system may have caused the change.
I found a similar thread here. It may help you.

The CLI calls into msbuild to get the default project type GUID to
use. MSBuild sets the $(DefaultProjectTypeGuid) for C# and VB projects
to the "classic" one to allow the CLI to add both "classic" and
"SDK-style" projects to a solution.
The classic GUID (FAE04EC0…) is then triggering a selection logic that
looks if TargetFramework or TargetFrameworks is set in the project to
determine if the "new" or "classic" project systems will be used. The
idea is that at some point only the new project system will be used
and the classic project system may no longer be part of VS in some
future update (this is the tone of a lot of comments on GitHub).

